# Using lodash to get a subset of an object's values as a pipe-delimited string

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to use Lodash to get the values of an object excluding a few fields.  Suppose we're given the following object:

```
var x = {
    id: 0,  // <-- id is excluded from output
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
};
```

Real-world objects are likewise fairly small and always have an `id` field, and the other fields can vary.

I want to generate a pipe-delimited string containing the values in this object (in no particular order), again excluding certain fields.  I have the following code that works okay.

```
var keys_i_want = _
    .chain(x)
    .keys()
    .filter(x=> x !== "id")
    .value();

var result = _.values(_.pick(x, keys_i_want)).join("|");  // --> '1|2|3'
```

The desired result for this example is `1|2|3`.

I am looking for a less verbose way of going about this.  Surely Lodash has a more direct means of getting the values of an object sans a few?  I wrote the code above less than 5 minutes ago and I already find it confusing to follow.

Can the last step, where we pick out the values, be combined into the `chain` expression?  Is there a concise and more direct way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the lodash function [`omit`](http://devdocs.io/lodash~4/index#omit):

```
var withoutId = _.omit(x, ['id']);
var result = _.values(withoutId).join('|'); // ---> '1|2|3'
```

Comment: This was the very thing I'm looking for.

Comment: This is it's chained form: `_(x).omit('id').values().join('|')`